# Sharepoint 2007 Userlist custom property

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have a custom event handler on a wiki page, which should add a Tag to a custom coloumn which I attached to the Users List.
The problem is how can I obtain a reference to the List in a event.
It doesn't seem to be in the `Profile` of the profile manager and accessing it with `Spweb.Lists["Userinformationlist"]` gives me an error for non Admin Users.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, check this out: [Elegant SPSite Elevation](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/06/elegant-spsite-elevation/)

Comment: Ok thanks for this one, now I´m a step further, but please allow me a follow up question.
I obtained the Field by Spweb.Lists["Userinformationlist"].item["user"].Fields["Tagfield"]
Which gives me a complete List of the definition, but I cant figure out how to Access the Value (which is not present in this object...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `SPWeb.Lists["list"].item["user"]["Tagfield"]`; this will return an object, so you need to cast it to your original field type.